# Is There Entire Function $|f(z)|=|1-|z||$ For All $z\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, entire-functions

Is There Entire Function $|f(z)|=|1-|z||$ For All $z\in\mathbb{C}$?

Looking at $z=e^{i\theta}$ we have $|f(z)|=|1-|e^{i\theta}||=0$

So this is an entire function with infinite zeros, which can not be by the identity theorem, So therefore there is not such entire function

Is this correct?

Comment: The problem isn't that $f$ has infinitely many zeros (compare to $\sin z$ for example). The problem is that the zeros of $f$ have an accumulation point.

Comment: @T.Bongers but $e^{i\theta}$ as $\theta \to\infty$ has no limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. Since $|z|=1\implies f(z)=0$, you can deduce from the identty theorem that $f$ is the null function. But this is impossible, since the null function doesn't satisfy the condition ftom the statement of the theorem.

Comment: So taking the sequence $e^{i\theta}$ is ok as $f(z)=0$ for all $e^{i\theta}$?
But due to the identity theorem an entire function has finite zeros, in contradiction ?

Comment: I don't understand why you call $e^{i\theta}$ a sequence. It is not. And there is no theorem that tells us that an entire function only has a finite number of zeros. How many zeros do you think the sine function has? Or the null function? What I deduced from the identity theorem was that, since $f$ and the null function are equal on a set which has an accumulation point (the set $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,|z|=1\}$), they are equal everywhere. In other words, $(\forall z\in\mathbb{C}):f(z)=0$. But $f$ cannot be the null function.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of the exercise, I'd go with the [maximum modulus principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaximumModulusPrinciple.html) and [minimum modulus principle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimumModulusPrinciple.html) and assumption that such an entire function exists:

- For $|z|=1$, $\min|f(z)|$ and $\max|f(z)|$ is attained on $|z|=1$, thus $\color{red}{|f(z)|=0}, \forall z\in \overline{B(0,1)}$
- For $|z|=2$, $\min|f(z)|$ and $\max|f(z)|$ is attained on $|z|=2$, thus $\color{red}{|f(z)|=1}, \forall  z\in \overline{B(0,2)}$

but $\overline{B(0,1)} \subset \overline{B(0,2)}$ and we have a contradiction, because $\forall z \in \overline{B(0,1)} \Rightarrow z \in \overline{B(0,2)}$ and $0=|f(z)|\ne |f(z)|=1$.